# Trying to Locate the Common or C Connector

Tags: hvac

[image]

I am trying to hook up a new Honeywell 9580 my old thermostat used batteries and now the new one is asking for a common cable.  I started to follow the instructions upstairs setup the Green as the Common.  Then went down to my furnace only to find out that all I am seeing is RWGY and two blank spaces where the Thermostat wires were supposed to be switched around.  I have googled online looking for more info on my furnace but it looks as if all information has been erased for the company other than a lawsuit over pipes.  Any help to acheive the required Common would be greatly appriciated.  I know I will be bypassing the fan control but if I can get this two work I will order the Venstar wire adaptor.  As these adapters can only be ordered online I need to know I can located the C wire first.

[image]

Comment: Can you post photos of the actual wiring at the furnace?

Answer (score 1):

The `C` wire should be the grounded terminal on the transformer.

[image]

You can confirm this by measuring AC voltage between the `R` terminal on the board, and the grounded terminal of the transformer.  You should measure somewhere around 24 volts.

Inside the unit, look for the place where a bunch of green wires meet up with a white wire, and attach to the frame of the unit.  Follow the white wire back to the transformer.   Attach you new `C` wire, to a convenient place along that path.

Comment: Hello I added one new picture.  I thing I have found the bundle you are talking about.  Could I just untwist the marionet and add my New common wire into that bundle

Comment: Yes, that's the correct bundle. However, that looks like a crimp connector. So you'll have to cut it off, strip all the wires, and connect them using a different wire connector.  Test the voltage between `R` and the grounding screw, before you move forward. Just to make sure you're getting the proper voltage.